# Can you alter the polling time interval (5 seconds) for delayed_job worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Delayed job is great, but I would like to change its timer interval to be more frequent (every 2 second) to meet my special need.

Is there a config or hard-coding anywhere to change it?

Comment: You should accept the answer to give the kind answerer credit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With DJ 3.0 you can add this to the `config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` file:

```
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 2
```

Comment: I added `Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = ENV['DELAYED_WORKER_SLEEP_DELAY'] || Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay` to `config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` in order to be able to control the delay via an environment variable (in `development` I reduced the polling frequency to `60` seconds; and in `staging` and `production` I don't even set it, thereby keeping the default value of `5` seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

`Delayed::Worker.const_set("SLEEP", 2)`

in your `config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just go to RAILS_ROOT/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/worker.rb, look for the line

**self.sleep_delay = 5**

and change it to

**self.sleep_delay = 2**

or whatever you'd like

On an earlier version of DJ I set this to as little as 0.1 so that the jobs in the queue get picked up for processing almost instantly and it works just fine.

Comment: how to change the delay if I installed it in a gem way?
gem 'delayed_job', Is there any way not to modify the gemfile, but change it at config?

Comment: Try this Delayed::Worker::sleep_delay = number_of_seconds  # in your RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb